# Secret files on Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a secret file that I need to read from a Lambda function. However, I've read that it isn't the best practice to store secretive information within the Lambda code. I wanted to know if there were any similar solutions to AWS Secrets Manager, but for files.

Comment: By "secret file" do you mean the content of the file is supposed to be kept secret?  What's a typical size of the file?

Comment: Store it in the [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the file in S3 and encrypt it using Key Management System (KMS). The key used to encrypt the file can either be Amazon Managed or a Custom Key (CMK). Give the lambda function with permissions to be able to use the key and read file from S3.

Here is the IAM role permissions:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decrypt-kms-encrypted-objects-s3/

And here is a sample code you can refer to :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-client-side-decrypt-item-with-kms-master-key.html

Comment: Would it be a better option to go with EFS instead of S3 since it is faster, lower latency, and supports more concurrent access according to https://dzone.com/articles/confused-by-aws-storage-options-s3-ebs-amp-efs-explained?

Comment: EFS is a network file system and ideally you would want to use it with Lambda only if you are already using it with your EC2 instances. The link you shared mentioned about EFS being concurrently accessible, is from NFS perspective. S3 is the storage of cloud and would serve the same purpose (and a lot more features). The advantage of S3 is that, you will have to pay a lot less for the storage and second you dont need to configure your Lambda function in VPC if you dont want to.